# Debug event-based Outlook add-in - TypeError: Office.actions._association.mappings[r.toUpperCase(...)] is not a function

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Windows 10 - Debugging via OWA (Edge Chromium or Chrome) is fine (and the event processes as expected) but trying to debug the same code via Outlook 365 (Microsoft 365 MSO (Version 2207 Build 16.0.15427.20182) 64-bit ) and attaching VS Code (1.70.2) produces the error

```
Exception has occurred: TypeError: Office.actions._association.mappings[r.toUpperCase(...)] is not a function
  at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\olk-launchevent-host.win32.bundle:15:362564
    at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\olk-launchevent-host.win32.bundle:15:359564
    at Object.next (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\olk-launchevent-host.win32.bundle:15:359669)
    at C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\olk-launchevent-host.win32.bundle:15:358581
    at f (foundation.win32.bundle:59:206)
    at y (foundation.win32.bundle:59:1587)
    at new c (foundation.win32.bundle:59:485)
    at r (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\olk-launchevent-host.win32.bundle:15:358355)
    at S (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\olk-launchevent-host.win32.bundle:15:362376)
    at a (C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\olk-launchevent-host.win32.bundle:15:337430)
```

```
/*
 * Office JavaScript API library
 *
 * Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation.  All rights reserved.
 *
 * Your use of this file is governed by the Microsoft Services Agreement http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=266419.
 *
 * This file also contains the following Promise implementation (with a few small modifications):
 *      * @overview es6-promise - a tiny implementation of Promises/A+.
 *      * @copyright Copyright (c) 2014 Yehuda Katz, Tom Dale, Stefan Penner and contributors (Conversion to ES6 API by Jake Archibald)
 *      * @license   Licensed under MIT license
 *      *            See https://raw.githubusercontent.com/jakearchibald/es6-promise/master/LICENSE
 *      * @version   2.3.0
 */
```

The Variable pane in VSC have expected values:

[image]

Any thoughts on what's broken?

Comment: Does your add-in have a call to Office.actions.associate in the JS file? See example here if not clear: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch#implement-event-handling

Comment: Yes..........................   ` /* eslint-disable no-debugger */
/* eslint-disable no-undef */

Office.initialize = function (reason) {
  Office.actions.associate("onAppointmentTimeChangedHandler", onAppointmentTimeChangedHandler);
  Office.actions.associate("onAppointmentRecurrenceChangedHandler", onAppointmentRecurrenceChangedHandler);
};

function checkAvailability(event, token) {`  ................. This all works fine in OWA.

Answer (score 1):

Try moving the Office.actions.associate call out of Office.initialize and add it to the end of your JS file, similar to the code in [event-based activation walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/autolaunch#implement-event-handling) and the [Smart Alerts walkthrough](https://learn.microsoft.com/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/smart-alerts-onmessagesend-walkthrough#implement-event-handling). Using the first walkthrough, I tested adding the call to Office.initialize and couldn't get the add-in to run, but it ran without issues when I moved the call.